# Is there a way to get a log of *active* computer-use?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, log, input-devices

I would like to log the amount of time I spend in front of the computer - so not uptime for the PC, but the amount of time where I'm actively using input (mouse/keyboard).

The worktimer workrave does something like that - you can set an interval and after that, it will display a break-timer. But if you don't use the mouse/keyboard for perhaps 30 secs, the timer is suspended. So it can be done.

The best I could find was procinfo, but does not seem like it. From the man page:

```
user:  The amount of time spent  running jobs in user space.

nice:  The  amount of time spent running niced jobs in user space.

system: The amount of time spent  running in  kernel space.  Note: the
time spent servicing interrupts is not counted  by the kernel (and
noth‐ ing that procinfo  can  do  about it).

idle:  The  amount  of  time spent doing nothing.

uptime: The time that the system has been up. The above four should
more or less add up to this one.
```

So "idle time" might be it, but it seems to be idle-time in terms of cpu-usage and not idle in the terms I need it.

I'm on a Lubuntu 20.04 machine.

Comment: I think you just cannot do that "natively", I think you have to build/write a monitor-like script that measure time you run applications in userland (from a list) & measures additions of all times (sessions) you did work/play with the machine. Another approach is to use a camera that measure (instead of saving film) the time it detects you (from face identification) on the chair on front of the machine.

Comment: What do you mean by natively? I'm sure what you mean by that. Workrave does it.

Comment: I mean from standard shell commands

Comment: hmm. seems like you're right, judging from the responses. I'm surprised no one has developed something like this (or perhaps I just don't know how to define the right search terms

Comment: I'm not so suprised as far as I don"t guess in which use-cases it can be both usefull and legal all the same. It relative to human-survey so ....

Comment: You might be able to build on this. The accepted answer works great for determining how long it has been since the mouse or keyboard was used. https://askubuntu.com/q/1368345/243321

Comment: Nice, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Workrave keeps a folder in your home dir .workrave, where there are detailed stats about your use of the computer, saved in plaintext. these can be loaded into for example R or Python to do analysis of time spent in front of the computer.

two ressources to get you going:
https://github.com/oysteinbf/workrave-stats/
https://medium.com/@ianmooreisme/getting-work-done-with-workrave-b80c4337aa79